# C# Datagridview Doubliclick event and Click event on a row

Tags: c#, datagridview, click, double-click

I have a datagridview in my C# application. The selectionmode is set to FullRowSelect. I have a doubleclick event and a click event when the user clicks / doubleclicks a row. Unfortunatly only the click event start although I am doubleclicking on a row. How can I distinguish between both events?

Comment: You should be both fired. To distinguish between both doesn't look easy. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171543(v=vs.80).aspx and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485676/how-to-handle-winforms-control-click-event-when-its-not-a-double-click

Comment: Ok thanks thats a good link. But then I think I will change my application behaviour.

Comment: Also - I have NO idea how I typed that first sentence! Sorry for implying you should be fired! I meant to write "you should see both fired" but somehow while editing the comment I ended up with what you see. How embarrassing :(

Comment: Thats the curoius thing about it, it does not fire both. Only the click event is fired.
No problem, I understood what you wanted to tell me^^

Comment: What events are you using? I just tried using the the cell_click and cell_doubleclick and both fired (checked by writing to console from the event handler). But yes - thinking up a change to the application behaviour is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: If I remember correctly I also used the both events you have mentioned. Very strange behaviour. Hope this will be made easier in newer versions of .net